# Firebase Database: Give access to webpage if user knows password?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, passwords

Overview: I have a button that gives a prompt to input a password. If the user enters the correct password, they get access to the webpage, if they don't they are given an error page.

My question is, with Firebase realtime Database, is it possible to do this without other people getting access through the console in google chrome?

I was thinking that if I put the webpages HTML code in the database and if the person gets the password right, they get access to the webpage (altering the webpage using the HTML code from the database). Would this be possible, or would the user still be able to the HTML code through local disk?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I think you are confused as your question is confusing...... you can just use firebase authentication, and only display info once a user has logged in / authenticated. Are you using a JS framework? If you do not use authentication, you will need to modify the firebase rules too, otherwise your read write access to your database will expire one month after creating it.

Comment: But what if I want to only give access to a certain person and not anyone who logs in?

Comment: If you choose to use some sort of password authentication for your web page, that in no way is related to Realtime Database. Access to the database is gated by the web site, it's gated by security rules that you define for that database.  And that's not going to work with any password system that you devise.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. One way would be to consider creating groups, i.e 1 , 2 , 3, 4 and each group has access to different information. A user would then have an id, and a group number. The solution is up to you.